# how to add Custom Size or Editing App Size

Tags: android, android-studio

Whats up everyone,

so i have an android device that acts as a tablet

its 10.25" Resolution of 1280X480

i installed Thinkware Dash Cam Viewer but the start screen where it asks for permissions, the button to click next is hidden. since its not playing nice with the screen size.

ive looked myself using android studio but cant find anywhere that references the sizing or orientation, just for kicks i deleted everything in manifest snd seems to have no effect.

i can send anyone the decompiled apk if they want to take a look.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Sizing is meant to be automatic. If it's not, there's something wrong with the library being used for the introduction slider.

Comment: @TheWanderer I’ll send you a screen shot as to what it looks like. On the device. And on studio.